# I'm having problems un-archiving an NSMutableSet with circular references

Tags: nskeyedarchiver, nsset, ios4

I'm having problems unarchiving an NSMutableSet object in my iPhone (iOS 4.3) app.

I have a subview of UIImageView that contains an ivar of type NSMutableSet. I have defined the NSMutableSet in the header (and synthesized it in the implementation):

```
@interface MyView : UIImageView
{   
  NSMutableSet *group;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *group;
```

The set contains references to zero or more objects of type MyView.  Since group is an attribute of MyView, the references to non-nil group members (MyView objects) are circular.

I encode this view like so:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
  NSLog(@"Encoding group for %@ -- %@", self.imageFilename, self.group);
  [aCoder encodeObject:self.group forKey:@"group"];
}
```

The NSLog shows a healthy group object being archived.  But when I unencode, I get an NSException:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

  self.group = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"group"]; // <- NSException here.
  return self;
}
```

The first time I saw this bug, I got a fairly detailed error message:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFSet count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable set object'

However, when I reproduce the problem, I get a far less informative message:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

The achive is created with this command:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:parentOfMyView toFile:myFilepath];
```

And opened with this one:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myFilepath];
```

Thanks for any help with this.

-- rich

Comment: Hey, i delited my answer because it wasn't right. I checked your question again and I seams ok. Try renaming group to something else. I'm sure the bug is not in posted code but elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks xpepermint!  I implemented a workaround where I instantiate each archived group's MyView instances lazily using a unique key that I assign when the MyView object is first created.